# How do I find automation when invoices created using Bulk Processing context

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I can see invoices created with Bulk Processing context but I am unable to find the automation. How can I find the automation which creating invoices in Bulk.
[image]